# How to evaluate a filter string programmatically in an Angular expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to evaluate filters programmatically within an Angular expression in a template.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
        <div ng-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 43},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData',
      columnDefs: [{ field: "name", },
                   { field: "age", cellTemplate: '<div><div>{{row.getProperty(col.field) | col.colDef.filter}}</div></div>', cellFilter: 'test' }],
    };
});

app.filter('test', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input + '!';
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

As you can see, in the cellTemplate for the 'age' column, I'm trying to pass through the cell data through a filter that is in a string in my column definitions (col.colDef.filter).

Is this possible?

I want to do this because I want to use just one template but define a variety of filters on each of the columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/GWha8/2/

Answer (score 0):

How about simply adding `test` as the filter instead of getting the `col`'s:

```
{{row.getProperty(col.field) | test}}
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWha8/3/).

Comment: I should have mentioned my intent - each column may have different filters and I want the template to reference them and evaluate them.

Comment: i see, not sure then, it seems offhand that filters and templates go hand in hand, i would suggest using a different template for each filter.  If the issue is the repeated inlined js, you could use the `$templateCache` and set `cellTemplates` like so `$templateCache.get('path/to/template.html')`

Answer (score 0):

The gridOption id you should be using is `cellFilter` (not filter). If you are not doing any other formatting that would require a `cellTemplate` all you need to do it set `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].cellFilter = 'test'` like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs: [
    {
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      field: "age",
      cellFilter: 'test'
    }
  ]
};
```

However, if you are do need to do other changes that will require a `cellTemplate` then you can just reference your filter by name right in the template (no need to define `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].cellFilter`) like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs: [
    {
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      field: "age",
      cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">{{COL_FIELD | test}}</div>''
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Woops - nice catch.  I cobbled that example fiddle together hastily and forgot to use 'cellFilter'.

BUT I really do not want to reference my filter by name directly in the template.  I want to use the same template on multiple columns that may have a variety of filters on them; not all columns will have the same filters.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can fix this in ng grid sources inside ngColumn, and use column cellFilter

```
if (colDef.cellTemplate && !TEMPLATE_REGEXP.test(colDef.cellTemplate)) {
        self.cellTemplate = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: colDef.cellTemplate,
            async: false
        }).responseText;
    }

self.cellTemplate = self.cellTemplate.replace(CUSTOM_FILTERS, self.cellFilter ? "|" + self.cellFilter : "");
```

2) you can create custom function which accept filter and return string

```
function getTemplateFilter(test){
return '<div><div>{{row.getProperty(col.field) | '+ test +'}}</div></div>'
}
```